# Vector with variable: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

Tags: python, variables, vector, range

I am trying to creat a ray vector which is supposed to look like this:

```
in_vec = Vector([i,1], [0.001, -1])
```

"i" is a variable in the range of 0 until 3 in the steps of 1

`i = list(range(0,3,1))`

The program should run all three options (in a loop?). I am running out of ideas how to solve this. Any kind of suggestion would be helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: This is not clear, as there is no concatenation operation in your posted code.  Please supply the entire test case and error message (including trace-back).